# pd.to_datetime to create hour adds not real date automatically

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have pandas dataframe with one column for hour that is int64:

```
>>>name    food     hour
0  Aiti    salmon   9
1  Nani    chips    10
2  Dofi    tomato   9
3  Bende   egg      11
4  Tafte   salad    12
```

I am trying to change the hour into datetime :

```
df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['hour'], format='h')

#also tried this:
df['hour']=df['hour'].astype(str)
df['hour']=pd.to_timedelta(df['hour'])
```

but it adds automatically  date and I get something like this:

```
>>>name    food     hour
0  Aiti    salmon   1900-01-01 09:00:00
1  Nani    chips    1900-01-01 10:00:00
2  Dofi    tomato   1900-01-01 09:00:00
3  Bende   egg      1900-01-01 11:00:00
4  Tafte   salad    1900-01-01 12:00:00
```

is there any way to change it into hour but without the :00 and without the date?

Comment: it's not *fake*, it's the default. you can't have a datetime object *without* date or time except hour.

Comment: `df['hour'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['hour'], unit='H')`?

Comment: @QuangHoang ValueError: cannot cast unit H

Comment: @Reut starting from your original data with `int64`, and you can try `'h'` or `'hour'` instead of `'H'`.

Comment: @QuangHoang It worked but still has the :00